# Tornado rendered index.html body is empty

Tags: javascript, python, html, tornado

I am strating out with Tornado and I am trying to render an index.html template with a static js script on startup.

Here is my main.py:

```
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web
import tornado.websocket
import signal
import logging
from tornado.options import options

import Settings

is_closing = False

def signal_handler(signum, frame):
    global is_closing
    logging.info('exiting...')
    is_closing = True

def try_exit(): 
    global is_closing
    if is_closing:
        # clean up here
        tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().stop()
        logging.info('exit success')

class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.render("index.html", title = "Home")

class Application(tornado.web.Application):
    def __init__(self):
        settings = {
            "template_path": Settings.TEMPLATE_PATH,
            "static_path": Settings.STATIC_PATH,
        }
        handlers = [
                (r"/", MainHandler),
                #(r"/index", tornado.web.StaticFileHandler, dict(path=settings["template_path"]+"/index.html"))
        ]
        tornado.web.Application.__init__(self, handlers, **settings)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    application = Application()
    tornado.options.parse_command_line()
    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal_handler)
    application.listen(8888)
    tornado.ioloop.PeriodicCallback(try_exit, 100).start() 
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

Here is my index.html:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>{{ title }}</title>
    <script src="{{ static_url("js/main.js") }}" type="javascript"/>    
</head>
<body>


    <h1>This is currently touching your sockets</h1>
    {{ title }}



</body>
</html>
```

When I request '/' I get a blank page. However the title is set properly and the js is embeded properly. Basically whole head is present, but whole body is empty.

Even more, the html reaches client properly (I can see that in chrome networking dev tools), in the html sent by server the body is present, but somehow not rendered afterwards.

What's happening?

Comment: What's in main.js? Javascript loaded from the `<head>` (without the `async` attribute) will be parsed and executed before the body is displayed.

Comment: I'm also thinking that something inside `main.js` may cause this problem. You need to show us the whole picture.